Can someone help me make this e-mail printing function?
# Function to print emails
function Print-Emails {
    # Connect to the Exchange Server
    $session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://XXX17.XXX.local/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos
    Import-PSSession $session -DisableNameChecking

    # Retrieve new emails that have arrived since the last check
    $lastCheckTime = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path "HKCU:\Software\MyScript" -Name "LastCheckTime" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if (-not $lastCheckTime) {
        # First execution of the script, no previous check time available
        $lastCheckTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5) # Assume: Check emails of the last 5 minutes
    }
    
    # Retrieve the new emails from the mailbox
    $emails = Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity "directprint@XXX.local" -FolderScope Inbox | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Items | Where-Object {$_.ReceivedTime -ge $lastCheckTime}

    # Check if there are new emails
    if ($emails) {
        foreach ($email in $emails) {
            # Print the email
            Write-Host "Printing email from $($email.From) with subject $($email.Subject)"
            # Adjust the print command here to send the email directly to the printer
            Out-Printer -Name "TOSHIBA XXX " -InputObject $email
        }
    }

    # Update last check time
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\MyScript" -Name "LastCheckTime" -Value (Get-Date)

    # End session
    Remove-PSSession $session
}

# Infinite loop that runs every 5 minutes
while ($true) {
    # Check and print emails
    Print-Emails
    # Set wait time (300 seconds = 5 minutes)
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 300
}

$emails = Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity "directprint@xxx.local" -FolderScope Inbox | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Items | Where-Object {$_.ReceivedTime -ge $lastCheckTime}

The error message indicates that the code is not properly formatted as code, despite my attempts to indent it correctly. How can I resolve this issue and successfully retrieve and print emails using PowerShell on my Exchange Server?

Start by posting the error message in full :)

VS Code finds nothing wrong with the formatting of this code. PowerShell does not validate indention like Python does. (It does report that Print is an unapproved verb.) Nothing will happen without the exact error message being put into the question.
